# Using BASH to rename folders with specific extension

Tags: bash, rename

I need help creating a script that will go through a specified directory and rename folders that match a name. In my case, some have (/Users/) .bak appended to them which I'm looking to remove.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: `find -type d -name '*(/Users/) .bak' -delete`.

Comment: `/Users/` is appended? You must mean it's part of the preceding path, no?

Comment: Sorry /Users is the directory and .bak is appended. I'm looking to remove any with the .bak extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove folders with a `.bak` extension in a subdirectory named Users

```
find /Users -type d -iname '*.bak' -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir
```

If the folders are *not* empty, you must use `rm -rf` instead

```
find /Users -type d -iname '*.bak' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

[`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) looks for folders `-type d` named somehow with .bak extension `-iname '*.bak'` and hands these names to [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs), which collects the names and removes them [`rmdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rmdir) or [`rm -rf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm)

*Update:*

To remove the extension (rename the folder), you can use a `while read` loop and [`mv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)

```
find /Users -type d -iname '*.bak' | while read d; do
    t=$(echo $d | sed -e 's/\.bak$//')
    mv $d $t
done
```

Comment: I do not want to remove the directory, I just want to remove the extension. ex: test.bak renamed to test

Comment: This works great. I added -maxdepth as I only only need /Users. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
find /Users -type d -iname '*.bak' | while read d; do
    mv "$d" "${d%.bak}"
done
```

Remember to put filenames in quotes, in case there's a space in a name.

`${var%stuff}`: remove the glob `stuff` from the end
`${var#stuff}`: remove the glob `stuff` from the front

These two idioms, when used in loops, are very powerful, and work in any Bourne shell variant (dash, bash, ksh, etc.)